# Removed Sudo access from only user by changing UID and GUID

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sudo

I mistakenly changed my UID and GUID of the active (and only) user on my raspberry pi server by changing the UID and GUID directly in the `/etc/passwd` file. I am connecting only with ssh as it is a headless server.

I had changed the UID and GUID from 1000 to 0 after misunderstanding some instructions and just generally being in a rush. I have no other users and cannot ssh into the server as root.

Now, when I try to use `sudo`

```bash
$ sudo ...
sudo: you do not exist in the passwd database
```

and if I try `whoami`

```bash
$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1000
```

If I read the `/etc/passwd` file then I can still see my user with the new UID and GUID

```bash
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep <user>
<user>:x:0:0:,,,:/home/<user>:/bin/bash
```

I don't have any privileged access and can only act as the user, I don't want to logout so as not to lose the session and lose being able to login again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably borked and you'll need physical access to recover it - pop out the SD card, mount it, and undo your UID/GID changes

```bash
mkdir tmp
sudo mount /dev/sdXZ tmp  # disc X and partition Z are dependent on system
# edit tmp/etc/password   # be cautious this is not your host system!
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain this in anymore detail? I have it in my SD card reader but I'm not sure how to find which dev node it is to access?

Comment: cetainly - check `dmesg` (`dmesg -w` to watch), or list out `ls /dev/sd*` before and after insertion to see what changed .. there may be several partitions `/dev/sdX1 /dev/sdX2`, etc. .. in such a case it's likely the first is `/boot` and the second is your `/` root filesystem

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks mate